# ExtJS Template for loop

Tags: javascript, extjs, for-loop, extjs4

I want to iterate through the array in ExtJS Template, but iteration does not happen.

```
var template  = '<span style="margin-left :0%;display:inline">|</span><tpl for="."><tpl for="pipe"><span style="margin-left :14%;display:inline">{.}|</span></tpl></tpl>';

var data = {count : '6',pipe : ['1','2','3','4','5','6']};

var tpl = new Ext.Template(template);
template = tpl.apply(data);
// append template to dom
```

I use [`.apply()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Template-method-apply) to apply the data into the template (which retrieves *count* object), do I need something like [`.overwrite`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Template-method-overwrite) for iteration and insert new elements to the templates? and I don't understand what's the difference between `.apply()` and `.overwrite()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`Ext.XTemplate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) instead of `Ext.Template`

`Ext.XTemplate` have support for `<tpl>` commands. `Ext.Template` don't.

- `apply()` - just process template with provided data and returns HTML fragment as string.
- `overwrite()` - first parameter have to be `Ext.Element` or DOM element selector. Then template is processed with provided data and result is used as new content of the element.

Comment: can you please explain difference between `.apply()` and `.overwrite()`??

Comment: if I add first parameter like `<p></p>` I get an error `innerHTML` of undefined.

Comment: `<p></p>` is not valid selector or `Ext.Element` object. For example this code use result of template processing as content of whole page body: `tpl.overwrite(Ext.getBody(), data);` `Ext.getBody()` returns the current document body as an `Ext.Element`.